# PowerShell AD Foreign security principle - Group Membership

Tags: powershell, group-membership

I have two different domains with trust relationship. I would like to query both domains to extract the group membership of the user in both domains.

Ex:
**“User1”** belongs to Domain1 and a member of **“Domain1_group11”** group in "Domain1". But same user is also a member of group **“Domain2_group22”** in “Domain2”,

I was using `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to get the group membership but I was told, *this method will  only give you the groups a user is a member of in the domain you are querying. . However when “user1” from “domain1” is added to a group in “domain2”, “domain2” does not create a user object in domain2, in fact it creates what is called a ‘Foreign security principle’ this is a special kind of object so the domain knows it’s not a user in its own domain.*

Im new to AD scripting, any idea, what is the best approach here please?

Thanks.
Venu

Answer (score 0):

If your domains are in the same forest and your account has the proper security, you can just run:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity User1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity User1 -ResourceContextServer Domain2
```

You may need to specify the server for domain 1:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity User1 -Server Domain1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity User1 -Server Domain1 -ResourceContextServer Domain2
```

Or something like this for a more general solution:

```
$Domains = Get-ADForest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domains
$GroupMembership = foreach ($Domain in $Domains) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity User1 -ResourceContextServer $Domain
}
```

Comment: Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership is not returning the group-membership and i get below message.
**Cannot find an object with identity: 'User1' under: 'DC=Domain2'.**

But i know that, there is a group in "Domain2", which has "User1" as its member

Comment: @Venu What are you using for the Identity?  Are you using the User Principal Name or SID, which identify a user uniquely in a forest, or just the samAccountName which identifies the user uniquely in a domain?

Comment: i tried with both _SID_ and _samAccountName_.

1) With **SID**, i get the error when i query the Domain2. 

2) But if i use the **samAccountName** (i.e.User1 of Domain1), to query Domain2, it is returning the group-members of the "User1" account of Domain2 (not Domain1)... (yes, there is an account in domain2 with the same name in Domain1)

i tried to query another Domain (Domain3) with samAccountName (i.e. USer1 of Domain1) and SID, but it returned 
** Cannot find an object with identity: 'User1' under: 'DC=Domain3'**
** Cannot find an object with identity: 'SID' under: 'DC=Domain3'**

Comment: @Venu Sorry, I've misremembered the parameter name.  It's `-ResourceContextServer` not `-Server`.  You can use `Get-AdPrincipalMembership -Identity User1 -Server Domain1 -ResourceContextServer Domain2`.  I don't remember if you need to specify both `-Server` and `-ResourceContextServer` anymore.  It's been a couple years since we demoted the last DC from our child domain.  I've updated my answer, too.